# Error in Passthrough elasticsearch DSL queries in trino/presto

Tags: elasticsearch, presto, trino

I am trying to run a dsl query in presto/trino
the format specified on the official website is :
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/elasticsearch.html#pass-through-queries

My dsl query is

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool":{     
      "must" : {
        "range" : {
          "val" : { "gte" : 1 }
        }      
    }
    }
}
}
```

Then i encode it in base 32 and replace it with the a_query_dsl in my passthrough sql query

```sql
SELECT * FROM elasticsearch.default."<my_index>$<a_query_dsl>"
```

I cannot figure out how to make this work i get the error :
Elasticsearch query for '<my_index>' is not base32-encoded correctly

Comment: is `SELECT * FROM elasticsearch.default."<my_index>$<a_query_dsl>"` actual query you invoke?

Comment: No i replace the "a_query_dsl" by a query dsl that i encode for example :     Actual query looks like : SELECT * FROM elasticsearch.default."<my_index>$<I5CVIIBPONSXG4=>" for example this I5CVIIBPONSXG4= is the query encoded base32 of a query dsl

Comment: Have you tried somethign like: `"my_index$query:I5CVIIBPONSXG4="`? Or maybe `"<my_index>$query:<I5CVIIBPONSXG4=>"`

Comment: I have tried both ,none is working